# RxJs - errors as `Observable is not defined` - what is wrong here?

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to set a observable to the `mouse` co-ordinate using `RxJs`. But i am getting error as 'Observable` is not defined.

any one help me here?

here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mouseMoves = Observable.fromEvent( mouseDown )
  .takeUntil( mouseUp )
  .map( function( mouseEvent) {
    return {
      x : mouseEvent.clientX,
      y : mouseEvent.clientY
    }
  })

  mouseMoves.subscribe( function ( cords ) {

    console.log( cords );

     // $('#results').html( cords );

  })

});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DveXxf3gy10edVSZ4ILq?p=preview)

Comment: Are you loading the rx library in the browser? Adding a script tag (before the script you've included) that loads the rx library will add a global object `window.Rx`. You can then access the Observable namespace by typing `Rx.Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rx.Observable` instead of `Observable`:

```
var mouseMoves = Rx.Observable.fromEvent( mouseDown )
.takeUntil( mouseUp )
.map( function( mouseEvent) {
    return {
        x : mouseEvent.clientX,
        y : mouseEvent.clientY
    }
})
```